# Copy folder from Source-Library and paste it to Target-Library?

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, library

I need to copy a folder from a SharePoint 2010 library and paste this folder into another library e.g. the folder: "myTestFolder" from  mysharepoint/sourcelibrary to mysharepoint/targetlibrary

```
    ClientContext clientContext =
            new ClientContext("http://mysharepoint/sourcelibrary ");

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web site = clientContext.Web;     

        ListCollection webSiteListsCol = site.Lists;
        clientContext.Load(webSiteListsCol);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("sourcelibrary");
        clientContext.Load(list);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I can't continue, how to get myTestFolder?

Could somebody got an answer?

Comment: Must it be done by code?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked good for me:

How to Upload a Folder and Containing Files in a SharePoint 2010 Document Library Using Client Object Model

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6581.how-to-upload-a-folder-and-containing-files-in-a-sharepoint-2010-document-library-using-client-object-model.aspx